# how to get the Integer to the pow Biginteger

Tags: c#

I tried to use BigInteger.Pow method to calculate something like `10^BigInteger` value but this method only accept integer number as exponent like this:

```
BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger x, int y)
```

so how can I use BigInteger number as exponent in above method?

Comment: Write your own method?

Comment: I doubt you really need `something^2.2 billion` or more. `int` should be fine.

Comment: While having [~10**80 hydrogen atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe) in universe, do you really need that big number.

Comment: Actually I'm new in this. May be I should change method.  should I delete the post? @EZI

Comment: If you're new, I'd say move away from BigInteger, unless you need really, _really_, big numbers. You can do Math.Pow with doubles, which can already hold up to um.. quite a lot. If you don't need a floating point, there's `long` which is 64-bits. What's your requirement exactly? Or if you talked new to SO, yes, you can delete your post if you deem it not useful anymore or edit it to improve it. The links are under the tag.

Comment: Actually I'm trying do implement a cryptographic thesis paper where I had to do **g^k** where **k** is big number and I declared it as BigInterger. I'm changing it to  Long. Hope it will works. Thanks for your help. Should I delete this Question? @Pierre-LucPineault

Comment: There's probably a misunderstanding about 'big numbers'. With **g** being only 2 and **k** 50000, this already gives a result of over 15000 _digits_. I'm sure you would be fine with int. Anyway a **k** over 1M would probably take an eternity to compute. But I encourage you to head over to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and check the limits on the different datatypes, can probably be useful. And you can delete the question if you wish. But it wouldn't hurt to leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `BigInteger` exponent, then one strategy might be to figure out how many int.MaxValues there are in your `exponent` and call `BigInteger.Pow` that many times (using int.MaxValue as the exponent). Then you can call it again with the remainder.

Not sure this will work, but it may help get you started. Code will hopefully describe it better than I can:

```
public static BigInteger BigPow(BigInteger value, BigInteger exponent)
{
    BigInteger result = 1;

    var intMaxIterations = exponent / int.MaxValue;

    for (BigInteger i = 0; i < intMaxIterations; i++)
    {
        result *= BigInteger.Pow(value, int.MaxValue);
    }

    var remainder = (int)(exponent % int.MaxValue);

    if (remainder > 0) result *= BigInteger.Pow(value, remainder);

    return result;
}
```